# Android Creating Dynamic Footer view

Tags: android, dynamic, view, fragment, footer

i'm trying to create a dynamic Footer View as shown in the picture 
so i have 2 fragments first 1 contains viewpager with footer View in the bottom
and the second contains listview.

so what i'm trying to do when the user clicks on expansion icon the listview will slide up from the bottom and the Footer view will be on the top of it. and when the user clicks on the icon again the listview will slide down and footer will be on the bottom again .
i have searched around and only found fixed footer and header tutorials

anyone knows how i can achieve that?
Thanks in advanced .

[image]